# Is it even possible to "visualize" this in the time domain?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I'm trying to understand single sideband modulation. If you want to conserve bandwidth and you don't mind complicated math, then SSB is for you. So far the only thing I could find online to help me understand the boring math behind it was this

http://thesearemyinterests.blogspot.com/2013/01/communication-systems-ssb-1.html

I think there are some good bits there... but then I got lost on SSB 2...

I need some more step-by-step than what's up there. How is the Hilbert Transformer able to phase shift every frequency in the message by -90 degrees exactly? Why is it when I try to do everything in terms of the unit step function alone, trying to take the inverse Fourier transform involves a bunch of convolutions, but when I express the unit step function in terms of a signum function the way that blog does it, it's easy to express the Fourier transform in terms of the Hilbert transform?

The blog does a good job at first of explaining how to get the graphical intuition down, and I got that, but I feel insecure about my abilities to derive this on a test (coming up in like 2 weeks).

I also don't get when anyone would use DSB-SC with a low-pass or a high-pass filter. The blog, which does an okay job of explaining some of the math, doesn't really expand on that...

Hope someone here can help me?

Comment: I removed the filters tag, it doesn't refer to the kind of filter you have in mind.

Comment: Oh... thanks Hagen von Eitzen. I guess it helps others not get misdirected to this question, but it sure feels miserable not even knowing enough terminology to classify my question :\